# Why IKVM doesn't support Jython library?

Tags: java, c#, jython, ikvm

We have a huge Java project and decided to port a part of it to .NET (GUI, etc.). To speed up process we're using [IKVM](http://sourceforge.net/p/ikvm/wiki/FAQ/#what-is-ikvmnet) (JVM for .NET). In most cases it works fine but when I reach to Jython code then it got stuck and then throws the exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` and after `PyException`. It occures within method `PythonInterpreter.interpreter.exec`.
Even for simple example:

**Java:**

```
class Main {
    public static String printIt() {
            PythonInterpreter pi = new PythonInterpreter();;
            pi.set("integer", new PyInteger(122));
            pi.exec("result = integer * integer");
            pi.exec("print('hello!')");
            return  "hello";
        }
}
```

**C#:**

```
var code = Main.printIt();
```

What restriction or limitation causes the exceptions? In general where to find all limitation of IKVM (already searched a lot, nothing relating to this case found). Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Using IKVM 8.1 and jython-standalone-2.5.3, JDK 1.8, .NET 4.5

Here is a stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "src_python\Util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from com.trueship.jyinterface import PyUtil
  File "src_python\Util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from com.trueship.jyinterface import PyUtil
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit.framework.TestCase
    at Java_java_lang_ClassLoader.defineClass1(Unknown Source)
    at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader.DefineDynamic(Unknown Source)
    at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader.LoadDynamic(Unknown Source)
    at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader.LoadClassImpl(Unknown Source)
    ...
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1275)
    at org.python.core.Py.exec(Py.java:1319)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java:207)
    at com.trueship.jyinterface.Jyb.findClass(Jyb.java:113)
    at com.trueship.jyinterface.Jyb.initUtil(Jyb.java:90)
    at com.trueship.jyinterface.Jyb.<init>(Jyb.java:77)
    at com.trueship.jyinterface.Jyb.getInstance(Jyb.java:102)
    at com.trueship.cordage.orders.JSONOrderParser.parseOrder(JSONOrderParser.java:41)
    at   com.trueship.cordage.readycloud.ReadyCloudApiClient.getOrders(ReadyCloudApiClient.java:302)
    at com.trueship.cordage.readycloud.ReadyCloudApiClient.downloadOrders(ReadyCloudApiClient.java:264)
    at cli.ReadyShipper.Windows.MainWindow.DownloadOrders(MainWindow.xaml.cs:75)
    at cli.ReadyShipper.Windows.MainWindow.<.ctor>b__1(MainWindow.xaml.cs:49)
    at cli.System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Unknown Source)
    at cli.System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You should post the *full* exception, along with all the relevant versions. Maybe it's just an OpenJDK version mismatch.

Comment: Which version of IKVM and Jython are you using?

Comment: Last IKVM 8.1 and jython-standalone-2.5.3, JDK 1.8, .NET 4.5